# Getting errors on Visual Studio when using HoughLines

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2013

I am new to cpp and opencv so please mind me if the question has an obvious fix. Whenever I try to run the example houghline cpp file found here http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html i get an exception error and the following messages appear

OpenCV.exe!cv::Matx::Matx(const int * values) Line 318    C++

OpenCV.exe!cv::Vec::Vec(const cv::Vec & m) Line 1190   C++

I can run other opencv example files with ease its just this one that is causing a problem. I also realized the imread doesnt work, could that be related?

Comment: Have you tried using other examples that is using `cv::imread`..? VS 2013 has [some changes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/06/28/c-11-14-stl-features-fixes-and-breaking-changes-in-vs-2013.aspx) and OpenCV hasn't been updated for it, yet. I would suggest that you use VS 2012 along with CMake for maximum compatibility.

Comment: Thank you, i'll try to do that now